# Backbone save: "success" not getting called

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm working on my first major project using Backbone. I've got a Backbone view called `SignUpView` with a method as follows:

```
register: function(){
    this.model.save({
        email: $('#email').val(),
        password: $('#passwd').val()
    },{
        success: function(model, response){
            console.log("Registration succeeded, congrats!");
            window.location.hash = '';
        },
        error: function(model, response){
            console.log("Registration failed, reason = "
                + response.responseText 
                + " (status "+response.status+")");
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

However, whenever I run it, only the `error` callback gets called. This leads to strange behavior such as the console logging

```
Registration failed, reason = Registration succeeded (status 200)
```

("Registration succeeded" is sent back from the server upon successful registration, otherwise it would say "Missing parameter 'password'" or "Invalid email format" or similar.)

I know I could simply catch the 200 status code in the error block, but I don't like the fact that I'd then have to be handling a successful post in a function labeled "error". I know it's probably something really simple and stupid, but I just can't find what's wrong.

Comment: try removing the "},{" before the success

Comment: That's there because `model.save` expects two parameters: one containing fields to update and one containing callbacks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem, according to [this issue](https://github.com/jashkenas/backbone/issues/2241), is that invalid JSON is also considered an error. If the server returns invalid JSON (such as `Registration succeeded`), then this will be handled in the error handler.

I changed my server response to be

```
{"ok":"Registration succeeded"}
```

and everything started working as expected.

Comment: Just noticed this hurdle and also hurled a few swear words Backbone's way at the same time.